# jquery small error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am very new at jquery and code, here i am trying to get the setTimeout event to be inside the .mouseout event but i'm not sure how to do that as i keep getting syntax error in my editor. Here's what i have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slidedown').hide(); 
    $('.trigger').hover( function(){ // enter animation

    $('.slidedown').stop(true,true).animate({
        height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
        }, 600, function() { /* animation done */ });

    }, function(){ // leave animation


$('.slidedown').mouseout()
    setTimeout( function(){
      $('.slidedown').stop(true,true).animate({
        height: '0px',
        }, 600, function() { /* animation done */ });
    }, 1000 );

  });
});
```

A small nuance, in this code the user mouses over a div, then another div bellow it slides down. Moving the mouse to the .slidedown div should keep it open until the mouse is removed. But will this code collapse the .slidedown div if the user doesn't mouse over .slidedown after .trigger but instead moves the mouse directly from .trigger to another area of page? I.e i need some kind of 'setTimeout' that is trigged only if the user doesn't move mouse over .slidedown after hovering over .trigger. Hope i make sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: **Off-topic**, but watch those dangling commas (like the one after your `height:` lines), IE7 and earlier will choke on them: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/literal-improvement.html

Comment: Less off-topic: Be careful with `mouseout`, it fires on parent elements as you move over their children (because it bubbles). You might consider `mouseleave` instead, which is IE-specific but emulated by jQuery (e.g., so you can use it safely): http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Comment: @Crowder is right a dangling comma after the last property of the object literal will choke IE7 and below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
$('.slidedown').mouseout()
```

It shoule be

```
$('.slidedown').mouseout( YOUR_CALLBACK_FUNCTION )
```

You should pass a callback function which will act as an event handler and inside that event handler you can call *setTimeout()* the way you have done it.

So the correct code would look like this

```
$('.slidedown').mouseout( function() {
   setTimeout( function(){
      $('.slidedown').stop(true,true).animate( {
          height: '0px',
         }, 
         600, 
         function() { /* animation done */ } 
      ); // animate ends here
   }, 1000 ); // setTimeout ends here
}); // mouseout ends here
```

Comment: hi thanks for quick reply. The above code makes sense but it also throws an error on the }, 1000 ); line.

Comment: @Heineken: **What** error does it throw? The syntax looks fine (provided you're not using IE7 or earlier, see my comment on your question). I'm not sure that it will do what you describe in your question, but it does seem to fix the syntax error that Arnab picked up on.

Comment: Please see screenshot of editor: http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/7819/82514978.png and with the entire code: http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/853/86562691.png

Comment: @Heineken: Doh, I missed that he'd forgotten to add `function() {` at the top after `.mouseout(`. I've fixed it for him.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks T.J and Arnab, this works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slidedown').hide(); 
    $('.trigger').hover( function(){ // enter animation

    $('.slidedown').stop(true,true).animate({
        height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
        }, 600, function() { /* animation done */ });

    }, function(){ // leave animation

$('.slidedown').mouseout( function() {
   setTimeout( function(){
      $('.slidedown').stop(true,true).animate( {
          height: '0px',
         }, 
         600, 
         function() { /* animation done */ } 
      ); // animate ends here
   }, 1000 ); // setTimeout ends here
}); // mouseout ends here
    });
});
```

But the other thing i mentioned about moving the mouse over .trigger but then away (but not into .slidedown) doesn't work. The .slidedown just remains open. :) :( I think it will be very complex to get a .mouseout event that has a kind of 'allow' rule for one destination of the mouse.

Comment: Try using ".hover()" instead of ".mouseover()" the mouseover event repeatedly bubbles when the cursor moves from parent to child and vice versa. The ".hover()" handles that internally for you it uses "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" for IE and delegation for other browsers.

Comment: Although the important thing is that your HTML structure is important here, I can only do a guesswork, try posting a fiddle from http://www.jsfiddle.net/ if possible so that we can take a look at it.

Comment: Hey, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KSudv/   I'm already using .hover, unless you mean replace .mouseout with .hover? As you can see in the fiddle it works except for it won't repeat (which i need it to) and moving over trigger then anywhere but slidedown makes the slidedown remin open :'(